# jQuery Post Button

Tags: jquery, ajax

I created a simple ajax call with jQuery but whenever I press the button to Submit I'm returned with nothing. It's odd. I see no errors on Firebug. The ajax file does exist. I'm at a lost with what is wrong with it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

$('#post').click( function () {
var user_id = 1;
var receiver = 3;
var message = $('#message').val();
var the_type = $('#hidden').val();
    $.post('ajax_posting.php', 
    {
    user_id : user_id,
    receiver : receiver,    
    the_type : the_type,
        message : message   
    }, 
    function(data){
    $(data).appendTo('#response');}
    )});    

</script>




<form method="post">

    <input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="asdf" />

    <textarea id="message"></textarea>

    <input type="button" id="post"  value="Submit"/>

</form>

<div id="response"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may be try to set your handler before the element is created, to ensure your dom is loaded before you set the handler wrap it in a $(document).ready

Also you'll need to prevent the form from submitting use `event.preventDefault()`

```
$(document).ready(
    $('#post').click( function (event) {
        var user_id = 1;
        var receiver = 3;
        var message = $('#message').val();
        var the_type = $('#hidden').val();
        $.post('ajax_posting.php', 
            {
                user_id : user_id,
                receiver : receiver,    
                the_type : the_type,
                message : message   
            }, 
            function(data){
                $(data).appendTo('#response');
            }
        );
        event.preventDefault()
    }); 
);
```

Comment: Binding to the form's submit event instead of the button's click event will probably be better at preventing the default behavior, and it will work if the user presses enter or something.

Comment: I tried both ways with type button and type submit but still received no result.

Comment: @jason328 what does `ajax_posting.php` send back?